# can someone tell me what's the problem with this SASS code?

Tags: css, sass, mixins

when entering the vale "xs", i get an error saying "(max-width: 575.98px) isn't a valid CSS value."
and when entering any other value i get the following error "This Breackpoint 'sm' isn't supported yet"
is it even possible to apply this idea with SASS ?
Here is my code:

```
$breakpoints: (
  "xs": (max-width: 575.98px),
  "sm": ((min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px)),
  "md": ((min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px)),
  "lg": ((min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px)),
  "xl": ((min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1399.98px)),
  "xxl": (min-width: 1400px),
);


  @mixin breakpoint($user-value) {
    @each $size, $value in $breakpoints{
      @if $user-value == $size { 
        @media #{$value} {
          @content;
        }
      }@else { 
        @error "This Breackpoint '#{$user-value}' isn't supported yet";
      }
    }
  };

  body { 
    @include breakpoint(sm) {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  }
```

i wanted to minimize the number of code i'm writing with this SASS mixin

Comment: What if you put the values in quotes? `  "xs": "(max-width: 575.98px)",`?

Comment: I have tried such a thing, but it didn't work also, so I finally replaced @each with the built-in SASS module sass:map and things worked 
you can check out the new edited code in my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

so i figured something out, check out this edited code :

```
        $breakpoints: (
  "xs": "max-width: 575.98px",
  "sm": "(min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px)",
  "md": "(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px)",
  "lg": "(min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px)",
  "xl": "(min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1399.98px)",
  "xxl": "min-width: 1400px",
);


  @mixin breakpoint($user-value) {
    $value: map-get($breakpoints, $user-value);
      @if $value { 
        @media (#{$value}) {
          @content;
        }
      }@else { 
        @warn "This Breackpoint '#{$user-value}' isn't supported yet";
      }
  };

  body { 
    @include breakpoint(xxl) {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Credit to Mr. Ahmed Murtaja @ahmed-izz-murtaja